# Colocando controle de avançar e retornar em Slide Show

Tags: jquery, html, css

Gostaria de saber como posso alterar o script de Slide Show abaixo para que ele funcione com dois controles de ação denominados Próximo e Anterior sendo que necessito que o Slide só mude o texto caso o usuário clique em um dos botões para realizar a mudança do Slide Show.

**Jquery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(function(){
        $('#slideshow h4:gt(0)').hide();
        setInterval(function(){
          $('#slideshow :first-child').fadeOut(2000)
             .next('div').fadeIn(2000)
             .end().appendTo('#slideshow');}, 
          2000);
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <div class="slideshow-element">Test 1</div>
    <div class="slideshow-element">Test 2</div>
    <div class="slideshow-element">Test 3</div>
    <div class="slideshow-element">Test 4</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.slideshow-element{
    position: absolute;
}
```

[Demo do Script funcionando](http://jsfiddle.net/Ryumaru/Sg2mh/107/)

Comment: Você tentou algo ?

Comment: Ainda não sei muita coisa de Jquery e JS.

Comment: Pra implementar os botões creio que seja necessária uma alteração considerável.

Comment: Você não quer mais transição automática, apenas os botões, é isso ?

Comment: Sim ta ótimo do geito que ficou transição automática iria pesar muito o site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fiz uns ajustes simples para o slideshow funcionar apenas com os botões *next* e *prev*, e não mais com transições automáticas:

```
$(function() {
    var $slideshow = $("#slideshow div:first").addClass("visible").fadeIn(2000);

    $("#prev").on("click", function()
    {
        var $visible = $("#slideshow .visible");
        var $prev = $visible.prev();

        if ($prev.length > 0)
        {
            $visible.removeClass("visible").fadeOut(2000, function() {
                $prev.addClass("visible").fadeIn(2000);
            });
        }
    });

    $("#next").on("click", function()
    {
        var $visible = $("#slideshow .visible");
        var $next = $visible.next();

        if ($next.length > 0)
        {
            $visible.removeClass("visible").fadeOut(2000, function() {
                $next.addClass("visible").fadeIn(2000);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Criei uma classe *fake* chamada `visible` para controlar qual elemento está visível no momento da troca. Essa classe é atribuída ao primeiro elemento logo no início, assim como a exibição (`fadeIn`) do mesmo.

As funções *próximo* e *anterior* são semelhantes. Primeiro é achado o slide atual `$("#slideshow .visible")` e então é achado o próximo elemento ou o anterior, dependendo da ação do usuário, ex. `var $prev = $visible.prev();`. Se o elemento foi encontrado `if ($prev.length > 0)`, é feita a transição:

```
$visible.removeClass("visible").fadeOut(2000, function() {
    $prev.addClass("visible").fadeIn(2000);
});
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sg2mh/109/)**</kbd>

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda.

Comment: @Rodrigo tranquilo! Ficou clara a explicação?

Comment: Sim entendi perfeitamente.

Answer (score 3):

Boa tarde,
Aqui deixo uma solução bem mais simples.

**Javascript/jQuery:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(function(){
        $('#slideshow h4:gt(0)').hide();
        setInterval(function(){
          $('#slideshow :first-child').fadeOut(2000)
             .next('div').fadeIn(2000)
             .end().appendTo('#slideshow');}, 
          2000);
    });
});
```

**CSS**:

```
.slideshow-element{
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
 <div id="slideshow">
        <div class="slideshow-element">Test 1</div>
        <div class="slideshow-element">Test 2</div>
        <div class="slideshow-element">Test 3</div>
        <div class="slideshow-element">Test 4</div>
    </div>
```

Esta solução é bastante facil visto que só corrigi a sua.
Espero estar a ajudar, os melhores cumprimentos.

Comment: Mas ele quer que o slideshow tenha botões de avançar/voltar e que o conteúdo seja alterado diante da interação do usuário com esses botões.

Comment: tem toda a razão. não percebi. caso seja necessario alterar o codigo o autor que me indique que eu ajudo :)